# Azure AD B2c - Permanent lockout policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I use default Azure AD B2C Sign-in User Flow for authentication in my web-application. I have the next default values configured for wrong login attempts handling:

[image]

I tried to set the duration from UI, but it allowed to set the values for Lockout duration between 5 and 18000 seconds (5 hours) only:

[image]

I need to **permanently** block the profile after 10 wrong attempts instead until the user reset the password.

How could I configure the duration to be permanent?

All other settings should be the same as default Sign-in user flow has. So if I need to use custom policies to handle my case, please LMK where can I get the snippet of this flow to change the lockout duration only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible via smart lockout.
You may be able to achieve this by adding custom logic to the `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` or `login-NonInteractive` technical profile's validation technical profiles using the [increment integer claims provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integer-transformations#example-of-adjustnumber).

Below is a start to how this could be achieved. Note, this is untested and `Disable-Account-Technical-Profile` would need to be implemented.

```
<!-- This technical profile uses a validation technical profile to authenticate the user. -->
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
    <Item Key="AssertNumberError">You've reached the maximum logon attempts</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="IncrementSignInAttempts" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Disable-Account-Technical-Profile">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>CountOfSignInAttempts</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AssertSignInAttemptsValid" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="IncrementSignInAttempts">
  <DisplayName>Unit test</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CountOfSignInAttempts" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CT-IncrementSignInAttempts" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="AssertSignInAttemptsValid">
  <DisplayName>Unit test</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="result" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CT-AssertSignInAttemptsValid" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>

<ClaimsTransformation Id="CT-IncrementSignInAttempts" TransformationMethod="AdjustNumber">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CountOfSignInAttempts" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="Operator" DataType="string" Value="INCREMENT" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CountOfSignInAttempts" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CT-AssertSignInAttemptsValid" TransformationMethod="AssertNumber">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CountOfSignInAttempts" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="Operator" DataType="string" Value="GreaterThanOrEqual" />
    <InputParameter Id="CompareToValue" DataType="int" Value="10" />
    <InputParameter Id="throwError" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="result" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Increment integer claim provider helped me to resolve my issue via using custom policy.